# How to set arrow indicator on Fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created one android application, which has nine ImageButton and three FrameLayout.

[image: This image has 9 ImageButton and 3 FrameLayout which is invisible]

On each ImageButton there is onclick event, which add Fragment to FrameLayout. When i click on ImageButton1, Fragment1 is added to FrameLayout.

[image: Fragment1 is Added to FrameLayout1 on ImageButton1 click]

I want to display arrow indicator for Fragment as i show in the above image. Right now i have put one background image on Fragment to indicate arrow on ImageButton. which has solve my problem temporary but as

```
> Mobile screen size change or fragment height increase this background image size also change, Which make the arrow narrow.
```

[image: background image arrow size change as width of Fragment increase]

```
> Is there any other way to display arrow indicator for each Fragment?
```

Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: Go for quickaction view.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with the QuickAction View which provides similiar functionality as you need.

Below are some library which will guide you how you can implement it.

1) [QuickActionView](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction)
2) [QuickActionView 3D](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)
3) [Quick action pattern in Android and simple implemention.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521455/Quick-action-pattern-in-Android-and-simple-impleme)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks For your quick reply @GrIsHu. Can i use custom layout in quick action pattern?

Comment: Yes you can create your custom layout and use it. @user3607917